# How do I get the src of images when clicked on Fabric.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

i'm making a website with Fabricjs. One div is going to be the canvas and another is going to have lots of images (hundreds). I want to be able to click on the images so that they pop up in the canvas. My question is; how do i get the src of the images when clicked on so that an img node goes into the canvas node. Should i make an array of addEventl... for each of the images?

(writing in javascript)

thanks as always :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en";>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CustomCase</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HeaderFooter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SkapaDesign.css">
    <script src="Jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="Fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="Canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="Wrapper">  
        <header id="Header">
            <a href="http://www.inet.se/" id="HeaderLink1">Om Oss</a>
            <a href="F%C3%A4rdigaDesigner.html" id="HeaderLink2">Välj Design</a>
            <a href="Framsida.html" id="LogoLink"><img id="Logo" src=LogotypHemsida.png></a>
            <a href="SkapaDesign.html" id="HeaderLink3">Skapa Design</a>
            <a href="http://sv.reddit.com/" id="HeaderLink4">Hjälp</a>
        </header>

        <section id="Body">
            <img id="UpperShadow" src=NeråtSkugga.png>

            <div id="LeftColumn">
                <div id="TextMode">
                </div>
                <div id="CanvasContainer">
                    <canvas id="Canvas" width="270px" height="519px"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div id="LayerMode">
                </div>

                <div id="IPhoneMode">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="RightColumn">
                <div id="TextureMode">
                </div>

                <div id="TextureFilter">
                </div>

                <div id="TextureView">
                    <div id="TextureViewInside">
                        <div id="images">
                            <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
                            <img src="Hajar.png">
                            <img src="Labyrint.png">
                            <img src="Martini.png">
                            <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
                            <img src="Hajar.png">
                            <img src="Labyrint.png">
                            <img src="Martini.png">
                            <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
                            <img src="Hajar.png">
                            <img src="Labyrint.png">
                            <img src="Martini.png">
                            <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>

            <img id="LowerShadow" src=UppåtSkugga.png>
        </section>

        <footer id="Footer">
            <div id="FooterSpace"></div>

            <div id="FooterColumnLeft">
                <a href="">Välj Design</a>
                <a href="">Skapa Design</a>
                <a href="">Om Oss</a>
                <a href="">Hjälp</a>
            </div>  

            <div id="FooterDevider">
            </div>

            <div id="FooterColumnRight">
                <div id="Facebook">
                    <img id="FacebookLogo" src=FacebookLogo.png>
                    <a href="">Gilla oss på Facebook</a>
                </div>
                <div id="Twitter">
                    <img id="TwitterLogo" src=TwitterLogo.png>
                    <a href="">Följ oss på Twitter</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="FooterSpace"></div>
            <div id="BottomColor"></div>
        </footer>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont write _onclick="getImageInfo(this)"_ for each img , #images img on click -> this would give you the attr of the image

Comment: Where is the javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to declare onclick for each img.

Try this: **http://jsfiddle.net/cEh93/**

```
$("#images img").click(function() {
    var getsource = $(this).attr("src");
    alert(getsource);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `onclick` on each image, you can attach a jQuery event handler to all images and get their `src` attribute (this will output the image `src` to the console when the image is clicked):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    jQuery("#images img").on( "click", function() {
        console.log( jQuery( this ).attr('src') );
    });
}); // ready
```

Comment: Do you need to draw then image onto the canvas, or do you need to use the HTML `img` tag somewhere else?

Comment: Draw into the canvas, but i think to do so i need to add the img inside the canvas and also add it in javascript, could be wrong though.

Comment: You must put the code in `jQuery(document).ready`: see updated answer

Comment: this is what i get in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Check out this JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ueu9c/. You get errors because the images aren't there but it does display the src

Comment: wher does it display the src? inside a var? i can see the images, maybe this is too advanced for me but i really need to get this done

Answer (score 0):

You can set the retrieve of SRC only attaching event for upper DIV (using JS), like that:

```
       <div id="images" onclick="getSelectedImageURL(event);">
                        <input type="image"   src="FärgadePapper.png">
                        <img   src="Hajar.png">
                        <img   src="Labyrint.png">
                        <img   src="Martini.png">
                        <img   src="FärgadePapper.png">
                        <img   src="Hajar.png">
                        <img   src="Labyrint.png">
                        <img   src="Martini.png">
                        <img   src="FärgadePapper.png">
                        <img   src="Hajar.png">
                        <img   src="Labyrint.png">
                        <img   src="Martini.png">
                        <img   src="FärgadePapper.png">
                        <img   src="Hajar.png">
                        <img   src="Labyrint.png">
                        <img   src="Martini.png">
                    </div>
```

To get current selected image SRC on click event...

```
function getSelectedImageURL(event){
    if(event.target.localName.toUpperCase() == 'IMG')
        alert(event.target.src);
}
```

Comment: nothing seems to happen when i click on the images, no event and nothing in the console...

Comment: You need to replace the "div id=images" block.The function itself you can test in separate file,create file: 'test.js' and add to HEAD of the document path to file <script src="test.js"></script>.You can alternatively open under DIV branches :<script type="text/javascript"> (copy paste function) </script> and reload the page just to see it works.